# yaml-cpp node diagnostics for meaningful errors

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I'm using yaml-cpp to parse a file like

```
Some Stuff
 - ...

Elements: 
 - Type: Fruit
   Name: A sweet sweet apple
   Size: small

 - Type: Pet
   Name: clawbeast
   Danger: Low

 - ...

More Stuff
 - ...
```

There is a predefined set of valid values for "Type". When I encounter an invalid type, how do I point the user meaningful diagnostics?

Ideally, I'd output something like

> Invalid Type "Ratzupaltuff" in config.yml line 789

or

> Invalid Value "Ratzupaltuff" in config.yml for ... / Elements / Type

What information is available from `YAML::Node`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`YAML::Node#Mark()` returns the location of the node, either position in the file, or line/column.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! A note: line and column seem to be zero-based, whereas typically editors start counting lines and columns at 1.